# Join query with multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables

```
places(place_id, place_name)
places_criteria(place_id, criterion_id)
criteria(criterion_id, criterion_name)
```

"places_criteria" have foreign keys to "places" and "criteria". I can get many places by one criterion.

```
SELECT p.place_id, p.place_name
FROM places p INNER JOIN places_criteria pc ON p.place_id = pc.place_id
WHERE pc.criterion_id = < some_id >
```

**How to get many places by multiple criteria?**

**For example**: Disneyland is a place (place_id = 1), it is "good" (criterion_id = 1) and "interesting" (criterion_id = 2).

places_criteria's data:

```
place_id   criterion_id
1            1
1            2
```

Now I want to get the places which are "good" AND "interesting".

Comment: I think your description of the problem lacks some clarity. Can you give an example of data in those tables, and an example of the result you'd like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hard coded version is to join the table on itself for each criterion you need...

```
SELECT
  c1.place_id
FROM
  places_criteria      AS c1
INNER JOIN
  places_criteria      AS c2
    ON c2.place_id = c1.place_id
WHERE
      c1.criterion_id = 1
  AND c2.criterion_id = 2
```

That is efficient, but requires dynamic SQL if you want to query a dynamic number of criterion_ids.

The alternative is to use `IN (1,2)` *(or a join, etc, to perform a similar function)* to get the answer to `Places with criterion 1 <OR> 2`, then using a `HAVING` clause to include only places with two different criterion.

```
SELECT
  place_id
FROM
  places_criteria
WHERE
  criterion_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
  place_id
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT criterion_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

```
SELECT p.place_id, p.place_name
FROM places p, places_criteria pc1, places_criteria pc2, places_criteria pc3
WHERE p.place_id = pc2.place_id and pc1.criterion_id = < some_id >
and  p.place_id = pc2.place_id and pc2.criterion_id = < some_id >
and p.place_id = pc3.place_id and pc3.criterion_id = < some_id >
```

But I have a doubt regarding my understanding of your question : why do you show us the `criteria` table ?

Comment: This won't allow for easy growth of the query when you want multiple conditions, so this solution is overly complex and very inflexible.

Comment: Queries like this are built in a program, the same that offers the ability to enter multiple criteria. That's why that's the common way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `in` to select from a set. You can use a subselect to get the right place ids, or you can use `distinct` as I do, which is probably somewhat faster in MySQL.

```
select distinct
  p.place_id,
  p.place
from
  places p
  inner join places_criteria pc on pc.place_id = p.place_id
  inner join criteria c on c.criterion_id = pc.criterion_id
where
  /* Either by name */
  c.criterion_name in ('crit A', 'crit B', 'crit C')
  /* Or by id */
  OR c.criterion_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Solution 2. Match all criteria. Do this, by checking the count.

```
select
  p.place_id,
  p.place
from
  places p
  inner join places_criteria pc on pc.place_id = p.place_id
  inner join criteria c on c.criterion_id = pc.criterion_id
where
  c.criterion_name in ('crit A', 'crit B', 'crit C')
group by 
  p.place_id,
  p.place
having
  count(*) = 3 /* the number of criteria */
```

Comment: hi, but "IN" means "OR" condition. I want to get all places which are "good" AND "interesting". Could you give the other answer?

Comment: As you wish. See edit. You still have some flexibility. You only need to specify a list of criteria and the number of criteria you specified, without adding additional joins.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the places that meet one of several criteria:

```
SELECT p.place_id, p.place_name
FROM places p
INNER JOIN places_criteria pc ON p.place_id = pc.place_id
WHERE pc.criterion_id = < some_id >
OR pc.criterion_id = < some_id2 >
OR pc.criterion_id = < some_id3 >
GROUP BY p.place_id, p.place_name
```

If you want all the places that meet all of several criteria:

```
SELECT p.place_id, p.place_name
FROM places p
INNER JOIN places_criteria pc1 ON p.place_id = pc1.place_id
INNER JOIN places_criteria pc2 ON p.place_id = pc2.place_id
INNER JOIN places_criteria pc3 ON p.place_id = pc3.place_id
WHERE pc1.criterion_id = < some_id >
AND pc2.criterion_id = < some_id2 >
AND pc3.criterion_id = < some_id3 >
```

Comment: The latter works for my need but how's about the performance?

Comment: @Emerald214 As far as I know, it's the best way to do this kind of search. Perhaps somebody else knows a faster way.